# DatePicker format does not work if set by input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, datepicker, kendo-ui

I have observable objects that update the input values in real time. The problem is that the Kendo DatePicker does not know when the input value has been updated so none of the formatting takes place. A sample of this behavior can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/basememara/kMkSd/

```
$("#sampleDate1, #sampleDate2").kendoDatePicker({
    format: "dd MMM yyyy",
    parseFormats: ["yyyy/MM/dd"]
});
$("#sampleDate1").val('2012/09/25') //no formatting happens => 2012/09/25
$("#sampleDate2").data('kendoDatePicker').value('2012/09/25') //works => 25 Sep 2012
```

The DatePicker is expecting me to always update the value through the Kendo object. How to I tell the DatePicker that the input value has been updated (shouldn't this be done automatically though)?

Comment: So, what's the problem here? just go through `.data('kendoDatePicker')`. The field doesn't get formatted because, apparently, the formatting function isn't registered to the `onchange` event of the field. Why? Because that would create a loop: Set the value through code --> value changed (event) --> kendo formats it -->  value changed (event) --> kendo formats it, etc.

Comment: The issue is that I am not even updating the input value. That happens automatically by a JS framework via observable classes (live-binding). I can update the class object as needed in code and it automatically reflects to the input values in real time. It doesn't even know that Kendo exists. I'm only stuck with doing a workaround like this (which I don't want to do): $("#sampleDate2").data('kendoDatePicker').value(this.value)

Comment: I see.
In that case, I can't be of much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: If I can only re-trigger the parsing function I would be ok with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should re-trigger the formatting function:

```
$("#sampleDate2").data('kendoDatePicker').value($("#sampleDate2").val())
//Set the contents of #sampleDate2 to it's contents, through the kendoDatePicker
```